# Apache redirect 404 for only the files that are not found?

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-404

What I'm looking to do is basically take all requests to a directory, and if the file exists, send it.  If not, send it from the parent directory (assume it exists there).  The files are large and there can be a lot, and the subdirectories will change frequently, so filesystem links isn't a great way to manage.  Is there some Apache config way of doing this?  e.g.

```
/path/file0
/path/file1
/path/sub1/fileA
/path/sub1/fileB
/path/sub1/fileC
/path/sub2/fileA
/path/sub2/fileB
/path/sub2/fileC
```

So, if a request comes in for `/path/sub1/fileB` they get `/path/sub1/fileB` (normal-case).  If a request comes in for `/path/sub1/file0` they get `/path/file0` (special-case).

Or maybe there's a way in PHP, if I could have Apache redirect all requests in one folder to a specific php file that checks if the file is present and if not checks 'up' a folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone who knows Apache, please fix the title to make sense? 404 != redirect.

Comment: Correct, 404 is "not found"... in the case of "not found", I want to send the file from some other location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^path/[^/]+/([^/]+)$ path/$1 [L]
```

This rule will rewrite a request of `/path/`*`foo`*`/`*`bar`* to `/path/`*`bar`* only if `/path/`*`foo`*`/`*`bar`* is not a regular file.

Comment: thank you, this seems to either be it, or be close.  does this end up sending a 302 moved to that location, or does it actually send the file from that location as if it were in the current path?  my preference is the latter behavior... i'll try it out...

Comment: This will cause an internal redirect. So the client will not notice any difference whether the file actually exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP can [redirect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to a parent directory.

Comment: that could work, if somehow i could get apache to send all requests to the php file that set the header... then it could basically check if the file was present, and if so send it, and if not send the redirect header... or even better send the file from another location.  so i guess i could use Gumbo's rule above to just re-write everything to the one php file...